# fix yaml lint too many spaces in a braces error?

Tags: azure, ansible, yaml, pipeline, lint

Hi I all i m getting a yamlint error on my runbook and whatever i tried i couldnt pass the errors could you help lease?
errors are in the loop

I have tried removing the spaces or wrapping up items in double or single quotos, nothing seems to be working . i hope someone can help me

```
- name: Rename directories to be replaced by symbolic links
  ansible.builtin.shell:
  command: "mv {{ item.original }} {{ item.new }}"
  args:
    chdir: /xx/tt/ll/
  loop:
    - { original: 'backup', new: backupbkp }
    - { original: 'db', new:'dbbkp' }
    - { original: "ini", new: "inibkp" }
    - { original: "lock", new: "lockbkp" }
    - { original: "log", new: "logbkp" }

 26:8      error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  26:43     error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  27:8      error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  27:36     error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  28:8      error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  28:39     error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  29:8      error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)
  29:41     error    too many spaces inside braces  (braces)

enter code here
```

Comment: https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rules.html#module-yamllint.rules.braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors you are experiencing with your YAML file are related to formatting, specifically with the spaces inside the braces.
Here's a corrected version of your YAML snippet:

```yaml
- name: Rename directories to be replaced by symbolic links
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    command: "mv {{ item.original }} {{ item.new }}"
    args:
      chdir: /opt/aptitude/aptitude-21.1.1/
    loop:
      - { original: 'backup', new: 'backupbkp' }
      - { original: 'db', new: 'dbbkp' }
      - { original: 'ini', new: 'inibkp' }
      - { original: 'lock', new: 'lockbkp' }
      - { original: 'log', new: 'logbkp' }
```

Changes made:

- I added single quotes `'` around all the values in your dictionaries for consistency.
- I checked the indentation and made sure it follows YAML's requirements.

Please try this corrected version in your YAML file. If you still encounter errors, it might be helpful to use a [YAML linter](https://www.yamllint.com/) or validator to check your entire file for any other potential issues as shown below-
[image]